# Unable to access a variable in a function which belongs to other function of same class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a GUI with tkinter in python.I am trying to access a variable in a function which belongs to other function in same class.Getting Frame2 object has no attribute self.workingarea.The error comes from tools function.I am trying to access self.workingarea from projectwindow function in tools function.line no:28

```
class Frame2:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.list=["label","Button","Entry","Text","Frame","RadioButton","Checkbutton","Canvas","LabelFrame","Notebook","ScaleWidget"]
        self.w2=root
        self.w2.state('zoomed')
        self.w2.title("IDE")
        self.w2.configure(background="white")
        self.tools()
        self.projectwindow()
        #=============
    def projectwindow(self):
        self.workingarea=Tk()
        self.workingarea.geometry('930x660+5+25')
        self.workingarea.mainloop()
        #================
    def tools(self):
        self.prop=ttk.Notebook(self.w2,width=self.w2.winfo_screenwidth()-int(self.w2.winfo_screenwidth()*0.7),height=self.w2.winfo_screenheight())
        self.prop.place(x=self.w2.winfo_screenwidth()-int(self.w2.winfo_screenwidth()*0.3),y=0)
        self.widgets=Frame(self.prop,bg="white")
        self.root_properties=Frame(self.prop,bg="white")
        self.properties=Frame(self.prop)
        self.prop.add(self.widgets,text='Widgets',compound=TOP)
        self.prop.add(self.root_properties,text='Root Window Properties',compound=TOP)
        self.prop.add(self.properties,text='Properties',compound=TOP)
        #=========
        self.widget_section=LabelFrame(self.widgets,text='TK Widgets',padx=5,pady=15,bg='white')
        self.widget_section.place(x=10,y=10)
        self.obj=labels(self.workingarea,self.properties)
        for self.i in range(11):
            self.btn_widgets=Button(self.widget_section,text=self.list[self.i], borderwidth=2, relief="groove",width=33,font=("",14,""),command=self.obj.label)
            self.btn_widgets.grid(row=self.i,column=0,pady=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown as `self.workingarea` is not initialized.

Interchange calls to `self.tools()` and `self.projectwindow()` in the `__init__` function.

TIP - Do not use 2 `mainloop` in the same thread. Rather use `TopLevel` widget